# How do I make this regular expression work?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, key-value, regex-lookarounds, logstash-grok

I'm creating my own ELK dashboard to monitor my finances.

I got completely wiped out this year, a combination of many things, but most likely just poor fiscal responsibility.

Anyway;

I'm a regex newb, and I'm having a hard time with this.

Is there a way to quickly match strings with many trailing and leading whitespaces?

Here are my characters:

```
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                Account:                                                                                                                                                                                                            ************0000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         Purchase Amount:                                                                                                                                                                                                            $10.00                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       Transaction Date:                                                                                                                                                                                                            November 10, 2022                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       Transaction Description:                                                                                                                                                                                                            UBER *TRIP HELP.UBER.C
```

Here's what I am trying in regexr.com

`(?<account>(?<=Account:)(.*)(?=\s*Pur))` 
And my results contain a lot of whitespaces:

```
                                                                                                                                                                                                            ************0000
```

I'd like to have all the transaction $KEY:$VALUE pairs as named captures for grok filtering my bank transactions.

**The results should be:**

`(?<account>($StackOverFlowSuperChargedRegex)`

```
**************0000
```

**Here is my regxr.com workspace link:**
[regexr.com/736tg](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

EDIT: I am applying this grok pattern to an elastic search ingest pipeline, but I am not opposed to using it for a logstash ingest.

EDIT 2:
@Paulo

Here is the content field after applying trim and gsub (without the dissect processor applied)

```
"content": "View Online Hello, As requested, we’re letting you know that a purchase of $10.00 was made on your RBC Royal Bank credit card account ************0000 on November 12, 2022 towards UBER *TRIP HELP.UBER.C. If you don’t recognize this transaction, please call us at 1‑800‑769‑2512 (available 24/7) and we’ll be happy to help. Account: ************0000 Purchase Amount: $10.00 Transaction Date: November 12, 2022 Transaction Description: UBER *TRIP HELP.UBER.C Thank you!     - Privacy & Security | Legal -   RBC Royal Bank | Royal Bank of Canada RBC WaterPark Place, 88 Queens Quay West, 12th Floor, Toronto, ON, M5J 0B8, Canada www.rbcroyalbank.com. ®/TM Trademark(s) of Royal Bank of Canada. RBC and Royal Bank are registered trademarks of Royal Bank of Canada. © Royal Bank of Canada 2022   -   Communicating Safely Online   Regular, unencrypted email is not secure. You should never include personal or confidential information in a regular email. Be careful when opening messages, links or attachments received through digital channels, including regular emails, text messages and social media messages. If you receive a message that appears to be from RBC that is suspicious please report it to us and then delete it. Do not provide personal information like passwords.   Need Help? To discuss your personal information with us safely, visit our customer service page. Please note this email was sent from an unmonitored inbox. Do not reply.   For current scam alerts and tips to protect yourself visit: RBC Cyber Security | Active Scam Alerts    "
        },
        "_ingest": {
          "timestamp": "2022-11-25T11:18:28.621402003Z"
        }
```

Comment: Maybe `Account:\s*(.*?)(?=\s*Pur)`?

Comment: I am not sure I understand where you are using the regex ? In an ingestion pipeline ? in Beats ? Logstash ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, this gives:
`Account:                                                                                                                                                                                                            ************0000`

Comment: @Paulo, I am using the grok patterns within an elastic search pipeline, but I guess I could use logstash as well..

Comment: No, don't, I was just trying to figure out what you were doing :D

Comment: Ok, the plan is to capture the needed substring and only use that capture. If it is Logstash, use a named group, `Account:\s*(?<value>.*?)(?=\s*Pur)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Tldr

Not using `Grok`, but I feel It may help

## Solution

```json
POST /_ingest/pipeline/_simulate
{
  "pipeline": {
    "description": "_description",
    "processors": [
      {
        "trim": {
          "field": "message"
        }
      },
      {
        "gsub": {
          "field": "message",
          "pattern": """\s+""",
          "replacement": " "
        }
      },
      {
        "dissect": {
          "field": "message",
          "pattern": "Account: %{account} Purchase Amount: %{amount} Transaction Date: %{date} Transaction Description: %{description}"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "docs": [
    {
      "_source": {
        "message": "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                Account:                                                                                                                                                                                                            ************0000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         Purchase Amount:                                                                                                                                                                                                            $10.00                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       Transaction Date:                                                                                                                                                                                                            November 10, 2022                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       Transaction Description:                                                                                                                                                                                                            UBER *TRIP HELP.UBER.C                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: PUT _ingest/pipeline/fscrawler
{
  "version": 1,
  "processors": [
    {
      "trim": {
        "field": "content",
        "ignore_missing": true
      }
    },
    {
      "gsub": {
        "field": "content",
        "pattern": "\\s+",
        "replacement": " "
      }
    },
    {
      "dissect": {
        "field": "content",
        "pattern": "Account: %{account} Purchase Amount: %{amount} Transaction Date: %{date} Transaction Description: %{description}"
      }
    }
  ]

Comment: "reason": "Unable to find match for dissect pattern: Account: %{account} Purchase Amount: %{amount} Transaction Date: %{date} Transaction Description: %{description} against source: View Online Hello, As

Comment: My source contains a bunch of other text strings, so I think it cannot dissect properly..

Comment: After trimming things down, I'm able to get my grok regex to work via: (?<account>(?<=Account:\s)(.*)(?=\sPurchase))

I do like that idea of dissecting though; thanks for the help!

Comment: Awesome well done. I went to dissect because generally speaking dissect is less heavy than grok.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed via @Paulo and updating my grok patterns; not the most efficient/elegant solution but it works well enough.

```
    PUT _ingest/pipeline/fscrawler
{
  "version": 1,
  "processors": [
    {
      "trim": {
        "field": "content",
        "ignore_missing": true
      }
    },
    {
      "gsub": {
        "field": "content",
        "pattern": "\\s+",
        "replacement": " "
      }
    },
    {
      "grok": {
        "field": "content",
        "patterns": [
          "(?<account>(?<=Account:\\s)(.*)(?=\\sPurchase))"
        ],
        "trace_match": true,
        "ignore_missing": true,
        "ignore_failure": true
      }
    },
    {
      "grok": {
        "field": "content",
        "patterns": [
          "(?<amount>(?<=Amount:\\s)(.*)(?=\\sTransaction\\sDate))"
        ],
        "trace_match": true,
        "ignore_missing": true,
        "ignore_failure": true
      }
    },
    {
      "grok": {
        "field": "content",
        "patterns": [
          "(?<transaction_date>(?<=Transaction\\sDate:\\s)(.*)(?=\\sTransaction\\sDescription))"
        ],
        "trace_match": true,
        "ignore_missing": true,
        "ignore_failure": true
      }
    },
    {
      "grok": {
        "field": "content",
        "patterns": [
          "(?<transaction_description>(?<=Transaction\\sDescription:\\s)(.*)(?=\\sThank))"
        ],
        "trace_match": true,
        "ignore_missing": true,
        "ignore_failure": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```